# Environment variable always reverts to old value

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I'm using Linux and want to update an environment variable. I set a new entry with

`export theKey=theOldValue`

and checked with

`printenv`

Now I have a new value for this key and want to update it. I wasn't able to find any "update" commands so I run the `export` command again. This seems to update the entry when running `printenv` but whenever I try to read the value from my code I get the old entry value.

Whenever I change the value I reboot the machine.

Since this isn't working properly I tried the following

- `unset theKey`
- `export theKey=theNewValue`
- reboot

When checking the value this variable reverted back to the old value. Does someone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you write those in your shell config eg bashrc?

Comment: @GordonBai sorry, what do you mean? I'm using PopOs and used the "default terminal app"

Comment: I mean where did you set your `export` entry in? In terminal session, or wrote it to a file?

Comment: in a terminal session, I opened the terminal and ran the `export theKey=theNewValue` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `export` command has the effect in the one terminal session you run it only. So you need to `touch ~/.bashrc` if you are using bash, and put your export entry in that file. Then to apply it in that session, do `source ~/.bashrc`. For future terminal sessions, this file will be loaded automatically.

See more info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: To fill: `For future terminal sessions, this file will be loaded automatically` for interactive sessions. For non-interactive login sessions, put the modifications at `.bash_profile`. See [bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). Usually people `source .bashrc` form `.bash_profile` to simplify and unify the configuration.